# jQuery / PHP POST not working

Tags: php, jquery

Everything seems correct, but blank values continue to get inserted into my database. It seems to not pick up the values using $_POST. I have tried $_GET and $_REQUEST as well, but the values still don't seem to get picked up. I know that a blank row is getting added to the database due to the static "Video" text that is inserted.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName"
               placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName"
               placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
               placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="view" class="btn bds-button btn-block">View
    </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required: true
        },
        lastName: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: "Please enter your first name",
        lastName: "Please enter your last name",
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email",
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/post-viewer.php",
            data: {'firstName' : firstName, 'lastName' : lastName, 'email' : email},
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(text){

            }
        });

    }
});

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$servername = "XXXX";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "XXXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$first_name = $_POST['firstName'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO viewers (demo, first_name, last_name, email)
VALUES ('Video', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo $first_name;
    //echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo $first_name;
    //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Have you used a web inspector to see if the data is getting through?

Comment: Do you have any response from your $.ajax request ? Have you tried to print_r($_POST) on your php file. Or have you tested your $.ajax's events success(text) and error(event) values ?

Comment: And also its important that does your browser acting in its default behavior. I mean in your question, your browser should not redirect or navigate anywhere, if it does a navigation your ajax handler not working properly I think.

Comment: There is no issue or errors writing to the database. It inserts a blank record. I've used Riggs suggestion, and just a quick dump($first_name) writes nothing to the file. The $_POST is not obtaining the values.

Comment: As David Nguyen suggested, you should check the "Net" or "Network" tab of your browser's developer console to see if the expected parameters are actually being sent with the request (and to confirm the request method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using the parse_str function:

parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Answer (score 0):

Please use AJAX like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/post-viewer.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
         success: function (response) {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
```

Comment: they are `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",` this as per your original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35041016/1

Comment: oh, and that downvote you just got, it isn't mine. (edit: **was** not mine) they removed it. Edit #2. they added it again.

Comment: What JSON do you see being returned? Is see an `echo $firstName;` Stop guessing and start reading the question and the code

Comment: @Fred-ii- hahahaha. It's OK.

Comment: Thats makes a bit more sense, but you could add a `success: function (response) {` and then alert that. Or even show him how to create a sensible response as a json array/object

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

On ajax method, try this...

```
var vfirstName = $("#firstName").val();
var vlastName = $("#lastName").val();
var vemail = $("#email").val();

data: JSON.stringify({firstName : vfirstName, lastName : vlastName, email : vemail})
```

Comment: Not actually necessary

Answer (score 0):

The problem with running scripts via AJAX is when you are developing you loose visiblility on whats happening when things go wrong.

So you have to come up with a way of getting that visiblilty back, there are a number of methods I use, here are a couple.

#### Write an output file containing info

```
<?php

function dump($str)
{
    file_put_contents('mydump.txt', $str.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
}


$servername = "XXXX";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "XXXX";

dump($_POST);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$first_name = $_POST['firstName'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO viewers (demo, first_name, last_name, email)
VALUES ('Video', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

dump($sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    dump("New record created successfully");
} else {
    dump("Error: " . $sql . PHP_EOL . $conn->error);
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Now you can check the file for what happened. Add anything you like to it using the `dump()` function

#### Generate a json object to hold info and return it to the AJAX call

```
<?php
$response = new stdClass();

$servername = "XXXX";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "XXXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$response->dollarPOST = $_POST;    

$first_name = $_POST['firstName'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO viewers (demo, first_name, last_name, email)
VALUES ('Video', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $response->status = 'OK';
    $response->statusMsg = "New record created successfully";
} else {
    $response->status = 'FAILED';
    $response->statusMsg = "CREATE FAILED";
    $response->sqlErrMsg = $conn->error;
    $response->sqlStatement = $sql;
}
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Now when you run the AJAX, look at the responce returned

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/post-viewer.php",
        data: {'firstName' : $("#firstName").val(), 
               'lastName' : $("#lastName").val(), 
               'email' : $("#email").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(response){
            if (response.status == 'FAILED') {
                alert(response.statusMsg + response.sqlErrorMsg);
            } else {
                alert('YIPPEEE Kia A Mum');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Also remember you can set a breakpoint on the `if (response.status == 'FAILED') {` and then use the debugger to view all the data returned in the `response` object. That saves you having to code lots of `alerts` etc

Comment: Thanks Riggs - I've dumped the contents of $_POST and it just writes "Array" to the text file. There are no issues writing the record to the table, other than the blank values. Any ideas?